# Printing all records with all the attributes

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am from PHP background and very new to Django.

I just want to see all the records with it's values for that I have write below code

Model file :

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
```

View file:

```
q = Question.objects.all()
    print(q)
```

In console it only outputs question_text.
How can I print all the records with all the attributes.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do it ::
 - Serialize in some format and show in json/xml
 - just print the values for debugging purpose

> The First way :-

You have to serialize the query set since the returned are of object    type in your view Files. You have to add a serialize class so that    the returned object will be converted to your desired format(for json    or xml format).

```
from django.core import serializers    
data = serializers.serialize('xml/json', Question.objects.all(), fields=('name','size',....etc which you need))    print(data) It will print the data in either json or xml format.....
```

> The Second way :-

or, simply run the below code :

```
p.values()
# <QuerySet [{'first_name': 'Linus', 'last_name': 'Torvalds', 'software_name': 'Linux'}]>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use of the `model_to_dict` function to obtain a dictionary from a model object:

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

qs = Question.objects.all()
for q in qs:
    print(model_to_dict(q))
```